# facebook 35 (SSL_CONNECT_ERROR)

Tags: curl, facebook, vps

Estoy intentando agregar las urls de mi sitio a facebook pero este no las reconoce bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que este problema no lo tengo con otros sitios, ya que las páginas los tengo en el mismo servidor (tengo un VPS).

Alguna idea de lo que puede suceder?

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes, 2. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla, 3. Revisa cómo preguntar aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4.¿Usas SSL en dichos dominios?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida y pos los otros dos puntos. En cuanto al cuarto te cuento que si, uso SSL en los dominios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de darle vueltas me di cuenta que el problema era que el dominio no tenía bien configurado el ipv6 por lo que me daba el error.

Solución: apuntar el dominio ipv6 al servidor.

En otros casos me encontré que este problema puede deberse al no tener el CA instalado, lo cual también da solución para otros casos.

Gracias y espero que si alguien tenga el mismo problema esto le pueda ayudar.

Comment: En 24 horas recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así estarás colaborando con la buena salud de sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D